# tokenize a string with regex having special characters

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to find the tokens in a string, which has words, numbers, and special chars. I tried the following code:

```
String Pattern = "(\\s)+";
String Example = "This `99 is my small \"yy\"  xx`example ";
String[] splitString = (Example.split(Pattern));
System.out.println(splitString.length);
for (String string : splitString) {
    System.out.println(string);
}
```

And got the following output:

```
This:`99:is:my:small:"yy":xx`example:
```

But what I actually want is this, ie I want the special chars also as separate tokens:

```
This:`:99:is:my:small:":yy:":xx:`:example:
```

I tried to put the special chars inside the pattern, but now the special characters vanished completely:

```
String Pattern = "(\"|`|\\.|\\s+)";
This::99:is:my:small::yy::xx:example:
```

With what pattern will I get my desired output? Or should I try a different approach than using regex?

Comment: See http://ideone.com/lm0ioP. What about `_`, is it special char for you?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew 's answer is right, since `"` should also be 'tokenized', but in OP's output, the following string should be `":yy:"` for `\"yy\"`. In this case, use `Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile("(\"(?:[\\w]+|[\\d]+)\"|\\b[\\w\\d]+|[^\\s])");` at line 13 instead.

Comment: @Mateus: I have accepted the answer given by WiktorStribiżew, but your version of the regex is better for me, since I am getting example_and_more here. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use a matching approach to match streaks of letters (with or without combining marks), digits or single chars other than word and whitespace. I think `_` should be treated as a special char in this approach.

Use

```
"(?U)(?>[^\\W\\d]\\p{M}*+)+|\\d+|[^\\w\\s]"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xu1mcM/2).

**Details**:

- `(?U)` - the inline version of `Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` modifier
- `(?>[^\\W\\d]\\p{M}*+)+` - 1 or more letters or `_` with/without combining marks after
- `|` - or
- `\\d+` - any 1+ digits
- `|` - or
- `[^\\w\\s]` - a single char that is either any char but a word and whitespace.

See the [Java demo](http://ideone.com/C8kalN):

```
String str = "This `99 is my small \"yy\"  xx`example_and_more ";
Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile("(?U)(?>[^\\W\\d]\\p{M}*+)+|\\d+|[^\\w\\s]");
List<String> res = new ArrayList<>();
Matcher matcher = ptrn.matcher(str);
while (matcher.find()) {
    res.add(matcher.group());
}
System.out.println(res);
// => [This, `, 99, is, my, small, ", yy, ", xx, `, example_and_more]
```

Comment: Great, Thanks! This gives the output [This, `, 99, is, my, small, ", yy, ", xx, `, example, _, and, _, more], but I would have preferred [This, `, 99, is, my, small, ", yy, ", xx, `, example_and_more], ie the "_" is combined with "w". Is there a regex to do this?

Comment: Yes, sure, I mentioned the issue with `_`: it is part of both `\w` and `\p{Punct}` and it depends on the actual requirements how to treat it.