# tokenize a c++ string with regex having special characters

Tags: c++, regex

I am trying to find the tokens in a string, which has words, numbers, and special chars. I tried the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    string str("The ,quick brown. fox \"99\" named quick_joe!");
    regex reg("[\\s,.!\"]+");
    sregex_token_iterator iter(str.begin(), str.end(), reg, -1), end;
    vector<string> vec(iter, end);
    for (auto a : vec) {
        cout << a << ":";
    }
    cout    << endl;
}
```

And got the following output:

```
The:quick:brown:fox:99:named:quick_joe:
```

But I wanted the output:

```
The:,:quick:brown:.:fox:":99:":named:quick_joe:!:
```

What regex should I use for that? I would like to stick to the standard c++ if possible, ie I would not like a solution with boost.

(See [43594465](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43594465) for a java version of this question, but now I am looking for a c++ solution. So essentially, the question is how to map Java's Matcher and Pattern to C++.)

Comment: The problem with your current regex lacks all possible special chars you want to split on. You will need to add all of them to the character class, or use `reg(R"(\s*(\W)\s*)")` with Jeff's code (if all Unicode letters/digits are not an issue here). Both mine and Jeff's approaches are OK for ASCII only input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're asking to interleave non-matched substrings (submatch -1) with the whole matched substrings (submatch 0), which is slightly different:

```
sregex_token_iterator iter(str.begin(), str.end(), reg, {-1,0}), end;
```

This yields:

```
The: ,:quick: :brown:. :fox: ":99:" :named: :quick_joe:!:
```

---

Since you're looking to just drop whitespace, change the regex to consume surrounding whitespace, and add a capture group for the non-whitespace chars. Then, just specify submatch 1 in the iterator, instead of submatch 0:

```
regex reg("\\s*([,.!\"]+)\\s*");
sregex_token_iterator iter(str.begin(), str.end(), reg, {-1,1}), end;
```

Yields:

```
The:,:quick brown:.:fox:":99:":named quick_joe:!:
```

---

Splitting the spaces between adjoining words requires splitting on 'just spaces' too:

```
regex reg("\\s*\\s|([,.!\"]+)\\s*");
```

However, you'll end up with empty submatches:

```
The:::,:quick::brown:.:fox:::":99:":named::quick_joe:!:
```

---

Easy enough to drop those:

```
regex reg("\\s*\\s|([,.!\"]+)\\s*");
sregex_token_iterator iter(str.begin(), str.end(), reg, {-1,1}), end;
vector<string> vec;
copy_if(iter, end, back_inserter(vec), [](const string& x) { return x.size(); });
```

Finally:

```
The:,:quick:brown:.:fox:":99:":named:quick_joe:!:
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Can you point me to a link which has a good tutorial and documentation on C++ regex?

Comment: After searching around, I found that the book "Professional C++" by Marc Gregoire, 2nd edition, chapter 14, provides a good introduction to this topic.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the approach used in the Java related question, just use a *matching* approach here, too.

```
regex reg(R"(\d+|[^\W\d]+|[^\w\s])");
sregex_token_iterator iter(str.begin(), str.end(), reg), end;
vector<string> vec(iter, end);
```

See the [C++ demo](https://ideone.com/Vf9iCF). Result: `The:,:quick:brown:.:fox:":99:":named:quick_joe:!:`. Note this won't match Unicode letters here as `\w` (`\d`, and `\s`, too) is not Unicode aware in an `std::regex`.

**Pattern details**:

- `\d+` - 1 or more digits
- `|` - or
- `[^\W\d]+` - 1 or more ASCII letters or `_`
- `|` - or
- `[^\w\s]` - 1 char other than an ASCII letter/digit,`_` and whitespace.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer and your comment. Both answers were correct, so I accepted the first one.